# How to guard against NHibernate incomplete mappings

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate/FluentNHibernate. I use FNH for my coding now as I find it is easier to use. However, I am working with some existing code base which is written in NHibernate. Today I found a bug in the code where the database wasn't getting updated as expected. After about 30 mins I found out that I hadn't updated the mapping xml even though I added a new class variable - so that row in the table wasn't getting updated. My question is, is there a way to identify such incomplete mappings with NHibernate easily so that I don't have to manually check the mapping always when something goes wrong? i.e. A warning message if I am updating an object which has non default data for any fields which aren't mapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the PersistenceSpecification class in FluentNHibernate: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing

You could wrap this up using reflection to test every property if that makes sense for your system.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use the NHibernate mapping metadata and search for unmapped properties via reflection in a UnitTest.

By using the Metatdata, it is transparent for your application if you are using fluent nhibernate or other means to create the nhibernate mapping.

If you test your mappings in UnitTests you will know during test-time not during application startup if your mappings are alright.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949221/how-to-find-unmapped-properties-in-a-nhibernate-mapped-class) seems to be related and [this shows how to query the metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856791/27083).

Comment: +1 I've written this style of unit test (though not this exact one) and they work a treat.

Answer (score 0):

The bug where the database did not get updated can be caused by issues other than not mapped field/property. There may be other mapping mistakes that are impossible to catch using reflection. What if you used wrong cascade or wrong generator? Or forgot association mapping?

If you want to catch majority of mapping issues you should create an integration test that will execute against real or in-memory database. Good overview of this approach is [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing).